# Why does this fix a heap corruption?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I've got code:

```
    float **array = new float*[width + 1]; //old line was '= new float*[width]'

    //Create dynamic 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        array[i] = new float[height + 1]; //old line was '= new float[height]'
    }

    //Hardcode 2D array for testing
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            array[i][j] = i + j;
         }
     }

    //deallocate heap memory
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        delete [] array[i]; //Where corrupted memory error used to be
    }
    delete [] array;
```

(For the record, I know it would be more efficient to allocate a single block of memory, but I work closely with scientists who would never understand why/how to use it. Since it's run on servers, the bosses say this is preferred.)

My question is why does the height+1/width+1 fix the corrupted memory issue? I know the extra space is for the null terminator, but why is it necessary? And why did it work when height and width were the same, but break when they were different?

SOLN:
I had my height/width backwards while filling my array... -.-; Thank you to NPE.

Comment: Your program has other errors. This isn't it.

Comment: If adding 1 to the buffer gets rid of the fault then you may have an off by 1 error somewhere.  Your example is incomplete however and we can't give you any more advice based upon it.  Also... I'm not sure you understand what requires a null terminator.  `float` arrays certainly do not.

Comment: `My question is why does the height+1/width+1 fix the corrupted memory issue?`  It didn't fix anything.  All you did was move the corruption bug somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following comment is a red herring:

```
   delete [] array[i]; //Where corrupted memory error used to be
```

This isn't where the memory error *occurred*. This is where *it got detected* (by the C++ runtime). Note that the runtime isn't obliged to detect [this sort of errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so in a way it's doing you a favour. :-)

You have a [buffer overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (probably an off-by-one error in a loop) in the part of your code that you're not showing.

If you can't find it by examining the code, try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or `-fsanitize=address` in GCC.

**edit**: The issue with the code that you've added to the question:

```
//Hardcode 2D array for testing
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = i + j;
     }
 }
```

is that it has `width` and `height` (or, equivalently, `i` and `j`) the wrong way round. Unless `width == height`, your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Or even better try the option `-fsanitize=address` in GCC.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Oh nice, didn't know about `-fsanitize=address`.

Comment: can't find a docs, so I am note it here: this option did appeared since 4.9 release; before this was an alternative option `-fmudflap`, but I didn't tried the last, so couldn't say about it. But the address sanitizer is indeed cool thing — it does even have a syntax coloring when prints to output about an error :з

Comment: Is commenting out code enough to see where the error is occurring? Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything other than VS2013. I added the code that fills the array to my post and removed the +1's in my code, but I can't see any reason that code would cause an issue. Everything else only reads from the array (before it's deleted), so I can't imagine that would be the issue? If I comment out the 'array[i][j] = i + j;' line, I don't get any corruption message.

Comment: @user2816987: The issue with the code that fills the array is that it's got `width` and `height` (or, equivalently, `i` and `j`) the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1):

Changing height and weight by height+1 and weight+1 is probably not going to be enough.
The code you posted was correct with height and weight.

This means that something was likely writing just past the end of those arrays in some other part of the code, and when you grew those arrays, it made the faulty code write right at the end of the arrays instead of crashing. You didn't fix the issue, you just hid it.

The code actually crashed on the delete[] due to some limitations in how the OS detects heap corruptions. Very often off-by-one errors on the heap will be detected by the next call to new/delete/malloc/free, not when they actually happen.

You can use tools like Valgrind if you want to know exactly when and where your program does illegal things with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't fix the code.  What you are doing is changing the executable with the new code, thus moving the corruption bug to another part of your program.

One thing you should *not* do -- **do not change your program to the one you say "works" with the `+ 1` and then accept it.**  I know it may be tempting if the bug is hard to diagnose, but don't go this route.

What you must do is go back to the non-working version, and really fix the issue.  By "fix", meaning you can explain what the fix does, why it fixes the problem, etc.